# SpriteRenderer vs Image(Canvas) perfomance

Tags: unity-game-engine

I create a 2d game in this game, objects will be shown on the screen (circles on the scheme). In the game, the circles will be destroyed by the player and from the bottom they will drive up above the new circles. Circle combinations will be built in advance so that there will be about 50 ~ 300 pieces on the stage.
I need performance on older devices. 
Of course, for performance, I will use a pool of objects and work(SetActive(true)) only with visible game objects.

What is better to use SpriteRenderer or Image(Canvas)? and why?

[scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wx3l.png)

Comment: I do not know an answer but it should take no more than 20 minutes to rig a benchmark that would give you a very good idea what's going to work better in your case

Comment: take the List and the Hashset. You can create two arrays and see which one of them will pass the Foreach faster. But will it give you an understanding of what is best for you?  I understand that the question is not simple, so I came here and did not ask people on the subway